# How does rsync preserve ownership when uid/gid differs?

Tags: rsync, ownership

Upon deploying a new server and migrating the entire contents of `/home` using `rsync` I noticed that the group and user ownership were in fact preserved, despite the fact that the ids differ between the two servers.

Specifically, the command I ran was:

```
rsync -avz oldserver:/home/ /home
```

Though I have recreated all of the same users and groups on the new server, most of them have different ids than the old, but somehow this command has magically kept the correct ownership (based on name) and assigned new gid and uid where applicable.  I am able to verify this with `ls -n /home`.

How is this possible?  Does rsync do some kind of name lookup?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, by default rsync matches owners and groups by name. Details are in the docs for `--numeric-ids`.

> --numeric-ids
>
> With this option rsync will transfer numeric group and user IDs rather  than using user and group names and mapping them at both ends.
>
> By  default rsync will use the username and groupname to determine what ownership to give files. The special uid 0 and the special group  0  are  never mapped  via  user/group names even if the `--numeric-ids` option is not specified.
>
> If a user or group has no name on the source system or it has  no  match  on the  destination  system, then the numeric ID from the source system is used instead.

`rsync` presumably uses [`getpwnam`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getpwnam_r.html) and [`getgrnam`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/getgrnam_r.html) to look up the uid and gid associated with the user and group names.

Comment: wow, had no idea that was going on behind the scenes.  thanks for finding this!

Comment: unfortunately it does not work as it should. it still tryes do some remapping when it will found the same names (user or group) on destination, with different uid/gid . I've got this 'joke' under version 3.1.3 debian 10 with transferring between two physical computers.

Comment: @Znik this works for me, after rysnc the gid and uid are preserved even if there is no such user in the new system. However, the command must be executed with root permission of destination folder.

Comment: this is in rsync manual. usually rsync tryes assign the same user on destination host, and if it is needed, rsync change gid and uid. if name is not found, then uid/gid is not changed, and is assigned to anyone user/group defined in dest. but you can add flag --numeric-ids , then rsync assign uid/gid as is without any mapping. destination definition in /etc/groups / etc/passwd finally defines maping.